# I need my app (Java, SpringBoot) to be able to send company Exchange e-mails. But there's a catch (difficult to configure)

Tags: java, spring, email, exchange-server

Long story short, I'm an intern in an IT company. I have a specific task assigned to me, basically it's a simple REST-based application that receives JSON's, processes them and stores them in the database.

I was assigned a new task, to add a functionality to send those processed JSONs in an e-mail.

Simple, right? I took a glance at Spring-Mail documentation, looked at some tutorials, and 40 minutes later my application was sending beautiful e-mails through throwaway gmail account.

But it turns out, that I actually **have** to use the company's Exchange service.

Thankfully there's an EWS API that provides all the necessary functionalities for that... right? Well, there's a catch. SMTP in the company is completely disabled, and I have a hard time configuring the application.

When I tried configuring the application like it's [suggested through EWS wiki](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide#using-the-library)  I did encounter some problems.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("emailAddress", "password");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
```

That's pretty self explainatory.

However, the hard part begins here:

```
service.autodiscoverUrl("<your_email_address>");
```

This just doesn't work, even with the overloaded constructor (that includes RedirectionUrlCallback) which is recommended. I've tried multiple combinations, but nothing works.

You can also enter this address manually, but where do I get it from?

In my company Outlook I've found some links, that could be fitting, like:
https://autodiscover.COMPANY.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

It however just doesn't work. When i enter this link in my browser is says that a service was created, another link that ends with /EWS/Services.wsdl is created, and it says that I should process it with SvcUtil.exe - honestly I have no idea what does it even mean, it's my first time I'm using the exchange and mailing APIs.

Where do I even go from here, do you have any tips? Should I try spring integration? What am I doing wrong? I'm feeling pretty down after wasting 7 hours on just trying to connect to the freaking mailbox, any help will be appreciated.

Not sure if it's relevant, but the Exchange version is 2016 CU4.

Comment: I'd suggest you look at doing some testing with the EWSEditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ it will allow you to test autodiscover and also give you the URL etc.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it did indeed provide me with the links - they're the same that I've got from Outlook though, and those don't work for some reason :(